# The quadratic variation of the following process...

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, quadratic-variation

Let $B$ denotes a Brownian motion, and a stochastic process $X$ is definied as follows: $$X_{t}=e^{3B_{t}}+\int_{0}^{t}B_{s}ds.$$

What  is the quadratic variation of $X^2$?

I got the following result: $$\int_{0}^{t}36e^{12B_{s}}ds+2\int_{0}^{t}B_{s}ds\cdot\int_{0}^{t}36e^{9B_{s}}ds.$$

Is it a good result? I calculated $X_{t}^{2}$, then I tried to find the quadratic variation.

Comment: First the integral term has zero quadratic variation second the term $e^{3B_t}$ could be written as a diffusion using Ito on B and F(x)=e^{3x}$ identifying the dB_t term integrating it and using ito isometry should lead to the result. Regards

Comment: Using my own hint I find : $9.\int_0^t e^{6.B_s}ds$ as from Itô I get : $d(e^{3.B_t}) = 9/2e^{3.B_t}.dt+ 3.e^{3.B_t}dB_t$ unless mistaken.

Comment: But the question is about X^2. Not simply X.

Comment: Ho ! you are right I didn't notice the power exponent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using "$\cdot$" as notation for the stochastic integral.

$$X^2=\exp(6B)+2\exp(3B)(B\cdot id)+(B\cdot id)^2$$

Using ito's lemma:

$$[X]=[\exp(3B)]=9\exp(6B)\cdot id$$

Using [integration by parts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It%C3%B4_calculus#Integration_by_parts)

$$X^2=X_0^2+2X\cdot X+[X]$$

$$[X^2]=4X^2\cdot[X]$$

Calculation:

$$
\begin{align}
[X^2]&=4(\exp(6B)+2\exp(3B)(B\cdot id)+(B\cdot id)^2)\cdot (9\exp(6B)\cdot id)\\
&=36(\exp(12B)\cdot id+2\exp(9B)(B\cdot id)\cdot id + \exp(6B)(B\cdot id)^2\cdot id )\\
\end{align}
$$

Therefore, I find

$$[X^2]_t=36\ \bigg(\int_0^t\exp(12B_s)ds\ +2\int_0^t\exp(9B_s)\Big(\int_0^sB_r\ dr\Big)\ ds\ + \int_0^t\exp(6B_s)\Big(\int_0^sB_r\ dr\Big)^2\ ds\ \bigg)$$

Comment: Seems fair to me.

Comment: I've found the mistake in my solution, but is it possible that you have missed a 2 factor in the very beginning in your answer? (a+b)^2=a^2+2ab+b^2

Comment: Yes, you are right. Thank you! I've edited my answer.